# ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope) returns nothing while ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope) returns too many results

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

I have downloaded a dump of OSM data from http://geofrabrik.de as a .pbf file. I have used osm2pgsql to import this data into my postgis-enabled postgres database. I am trying to get the geometries that are contained within a bounding box that I have created. Using ST_Intersects gives more data since that is the intersection of the 'way' and the envelope I created.Using ST_Contains doesn't return anything. My queries are like this:

Using ST_Intersects:

```
    SELECT name, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326)) FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE 
    ST_Intersects (way, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope((-122.1358332),
                    (37.494456), (-121.9858223),(37.594456), 94326), 900913));
```

Using ST_Contains:

```
    SELECT name, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326)) FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE 
    ST_Contains (ST_MakeEnvelope((-122.1358332),
                    (37.494456), (-121.9858223),(37.594456), 94326), ST_Transform(way,94326));
```

ST_Intersects seems to return too much data, I just have several megs of data returned.
ST_Contains seems to return almost nothing. What is wrong here?

Comment: Everything seems to work exactly as it should. You sure you don't want the intersection instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's because intersection doesn't just give me the points inside my envelope... I just want the ones inside my bounding box. Contains doesn't seem to do that correctly or there is something wrong with my query.